Prisma client not being generated from within a aws lambda container
So we have a distributed system that we have a package that we will call: mydatabasepackage.
This package has the prisma configuration and all migrations.
When we try to import this in a dockerfile to publish on lambda, it works with some AWS accounts but other AWS accounts asks to generate the client again.
We create this docker image on a pipeline and publish to AWS ECR as a lambda, the client is generated during a GitHub pipeline and the command does run sucessfully. However when the lambda is actually ran it complains to have no client and asks to generate.
This is the dockerfile in question:
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM node:20 AS builder

# Install pnpm
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install OpenSSL
RUN  apt-get install -y openssl

# Copy package.json and pnpm-lock.yaml
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./


# Set the environment variable for the authentication token
ARG NODE_AUTH_TOKEN
ENV NODE_AUTH_TOKEN=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}


# Configure pnpm to use the custom registry and authentication token
RUN pnpm config set '//EXCLUDED FOR PRIVACY/api/npm/nn-npm/:_authToken' "${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}"
&& \
    pnpm config set registry https://EXCLUDED FOR PRIVACY//api/npm/nn-npm/

# Install dependencies using pnpm
RUN pnpm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

RUN pnpm add -D prisma

#Generate the Prisma CLI
RUN pnpm exec prisma generate --schema=./node_modules/dfado/prisma/schema.prisma


# Build the TypeScript code
RUN pnpm run build

# Stage 2: Create the final image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20

#Install PNPM
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Set the environment variable for the authentication token
ARG NODE_AUTH_TOKEN
ENV NODE_AUTH_TOKEN=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}

# Configure pnpm to use the custom registry and authentication token
RUN pnpm config set '//EXCLUDED FOR PRIVACY/api/npm/nn-npm/:_authToken' "${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}"
&& \
    pnpm config set registry https://EXCLUDED FOR PRIVACY/artifactory/api/npm/nn-npm/


# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/task

RUN  dnf install -y openssl

# Copy the built application from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/ ./

ENV PRISMA_CLI_BINARY_TARGETS=rhel-openssl-3.0.x

#Install Prisma
RUN pnpm add -D prisma

#Generate the Prisma CLI
RUN pnpm exec prisma generate --schema=./node_modules/mydatabasepackage/prisma/schema.prisma

# Set the environment variable for the handler
ARG HANDLER_NAME
ENV HANDLER_NAME=${HANDLER_NAME}

# Create a wrapper.js file
RUN printf '%s\n' \
    "const handler = require('./' + process.env.HANDLER_NAME).handler;" \
    "exports.handler = async (event, context) => {" \
    "  return handler(event, context);" \
    "};" > ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/wrapper.js

RUN cat ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/wrapper.js

# Set the wrapper.js as the Lambda handler

CMD ["wrapper.handler"]

The code we run on the lambda is fairly simple: it just gets DATABASE_URL from secrets and creates a instance of prisma client:
import {
  SecretsManagerClient,
  GetSecretValueCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
let prisma: PrismaClient;

export async function getPrismaClient() {
  // Retrieve the secret name from environment variables
  const secretName = process.env.SECRET_NAME!;


  if (!secretName) {
    return new PrismaClient();
  }

  const url = await getDatabaseUrl(secretName);

  //Set it for migrations
  process.env.DATABASE_URL = url;

  //Create the client
  try {
    prisma = new PrismaClient({
      datasources: {
        db: {
          url,
        },
      },
      log: ["info", "warn", "error"],
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return prisma;
}

The client should be generated and the prisma client should start.
